# Deactivate a CSS class for mobile devices only

Tags: css, wordpress

First of all, sorry, i'm a CSS beginner.

I'm dealing with a wordpress website made with a custom theme. It has this CSS class i'd like to deactivate on the mobile version of the website, since it makes everything overlap:

```
.fullScreenHeight {
    content: 'viewport-units-buggyfill; height: 100vh;';
}

.fullScreenHeight {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

So far i've tried with different solutions like:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {.fullScreenHeight { 
    height: 100%;
}}
```

But they don't seem to work.

Any idea?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Your solution looks fine. Why are you trying to change the height from `100vh` to `100%`? Is your css coming AFTER the existing styles? Also - check the screen width of the device you are testing on - could be smaller than 320px or larger than 480px, meaning the media query doesn't match...

Comment: Hey Richard, you gave me an idea. I added !important at the end of the line and now it works. Thank you :) You can write the solution if you want and i'll mark it as the correct one.

Comment: You should also change the `content` property to have an empty value. In some specific instances, there's a script that will take the value of the `content` and inject CSS in to a `<style>` tag to add the 100vh effect on what it considers to be 'buggy' browsers i.e. some versions of Safari.

Comment: Ok Nikki, i'll do it, thank you too!

Comment: Why not a `display: none;` if you wish to completely "deactivate" this class?

Comment: OP states that it makes things overlap, which is the issue -- the overlapping specifically. So we can derive from the original post that they want the content to display, therefore `display: none;` isn't a solution to their problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {.fullScreenHeight { 
    content: '';
    height: 100% !important;
}}
```

Thanks everybody for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like that.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  .classname-to-deactive{
     display: none;
  }
}
```

You can give the priority class name to

```
z-index: 9999999; 
display: block;
```

Comment: He doesn't want to hide the element, he just wants to disable the effect of a certain class while in mobile.

Comment: @ThomasScheffer I thought he want to be disable the class name.

Answer (score 0):

It should not be that tough, try following css:-

```
@media screen only and (max-width:800px) and (min-width:300px){
.fullScreenHeight{
height:100vh!important;
}}
```

You can change the height whatever you want.